# How to detect navigation bar style is gesture or three buttons or two

Tags: android

I've test

```
ViewConfiguration.get(this).hasPermanentMenuKey()
KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
```

but both return false when navigation bar is gesture or two buttons.

is there any ways to know what kind of navigation bar is using?